# Some Limit Problem from Spivak

Tags: calculus, integration

I found the following problem from Spivak. Let $f$ be integrable on $[0,1]$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L$. Compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt$.

Here is my attempt: Define $H(x)=x^2\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,dt$. The limit in question is $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{H(x)-H(0)}{x-0}$. So can I just compute $H'(x)$ directly and set $x=0$ (or set the limit as $x\to 0^+$)?

Comment: **If** $\lim_{x\to 0^+} H'(x)$ exists, then you can do that.

Comment: Yes, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} H'(x)$ exists. But why we the limit is the same as the limit in question?

Comment: How do you know it exists?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to guess the limit. Suppose $f(x) = L$ for all $x$ then a direct
evaluation shows that the limit would be $L$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and find a $\delta>0$ such that
if $x \in [0,\delta]$ then $|f(x)-L| < {1 \over 2} \epsilon$.

\begin{eqnarray}
| x \int_x^1 {f(t) \over t^2} dt -L | &=& | x \int_x^\delta {f(t) \over t^2} dt -L -  x \int_\delta^1 {f(t) \over t^2} dt| \\
&=& | x \int_x^\delta {L \over t^2} dt -L| + |x \int_x^\delta {f(t)-L \over t^2} dt | + | x \int_\delta^1 {f(t) \over t^2} dt| \\
&\le& x {L \over \delta} + x{1 \over 2} \epsilon ({1 \over x} - {1 \over \delta}) + x {1 \over \delta^2} \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt \\
&\le&x {L \over \delta} + {1 \over 2} \epsilon + x {1 \over \delta^2} \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt \\
\end{eqnarray}
Now choose $\delta'>0$ such that $\delta' \le \delta$ so that
$\delta' {L \over \delta} + \delta' {1 \over \delta^2} \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt < {1 \over 2 } \epsilon$.

Then, if $x \in [0,\delta']$ we have
$| x \int_x^1 {f(t) \over t^2} dt -L | < \epsilon$.